# Gtk::Window set_visible results in a blank window

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, gtk3

I'm writing a application that resides in Tray, when user left-click it's show a window(not decorated, and positioned according StatusIcon).

After I run application and click in Icon the Window is shown correct, but after be hide (set_visible(false)) and re-shown I get a blank window.

I've tried a lot of things(I don't remember any more :/) but doesn't solve.

[The code](https://github.com/hotvic/HVMixer/blob/master/src/hvmixer.cpp); TrayIcon::on_button_release is where window is show and hide through set_visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set_visible() is a convenience around show() and hide(). show() guarantees only the current widget becomes visible, not its children. You probably want to call show_all(), to recursively show all the contents.

Comment: I already tried use hide() and show_all() instead set_visible, but doesn't help